# PHP MYSQL CASE substitution in array

Tags: php, mysql, case

Morning all, happy new year!

I am trying to select all records within a MYSQL database into an array where 1 column matches a list, and then replace the output of the cells when selected from that column.

It's a sports table, and I have the Positions as MF, DF, CF and want to replace them with Midfield, Defence, and Forward respectively.

I was hoping that the following would crack it, but get an error message, which lines up to the FROM line:

> Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/peterborough/www/www/wp-content/plugins/insert-php/insert_php.php(48) : eval()’d code on line 14

```
   $result = mysql_query("SELECT *,
                        CASE Position 
                          WHEN 'DF' THEN 'Defence'
                          WHEN 'MF' THEN 'Midfield'
                          WHEN 'CF' THEN 'Forward'
                      FROM People 
                      WHERE
                         (Position='DF' or
                          Position='MF' or
                          Position='CF') and
                          Season = '2014'
                      ORDER BY Number");
  while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){...}
```

Thanks guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have a syntax error in your SQL:
 the `CASE` expression requires an `END`

```
  SELECT *,
    CASE Position 
      WHEN 'DF' THEN 'Defence'
      WHEN 'MF' THEN 'Midfield'
      WHEN 'CF' THEN 'Forward'
    END AS position_long
  FROM People 
  WHERE
     (Position='DF' or
      Position='MF' or
      Position='CF') and
      Season = '2014'
  ORDER BY Number
```

Explanation:
when the syntax error hits, you get a `FALSE` from the `mysql_query()` call and 
when that's passed into `mysql_fetch_assoc()` *it* complains about being given a *boolean* instead of a *resource*

Comment: Ahhh that helps!! although it's now syntaxing, it's not doing the substitution?

Comment: not sure what you mean. it's not substituting - you're adding a new column to the results, you probably want `AS position_long` or similar after the `END` so that the new column gets a sensible name instead of the default name.

Comment: Of course! sorry, forgot the basics!! Thought it would dynamically change it, rather than create a new column!!